# Invalid Binary Error after App Store submission

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I'm constantly getting the following Error: [image: Invalid Signature Error]

after submitting my app to the App Store. I've tried everything recommended in Apple's mail and also the answers to posts I found on Stackoverflow. Nevertheless I'm still getting this message. What could be my problem?
What I've done so far:

- Checked to use App Store Distribution provisoning profile
- Checked that Entitlements.plist's 'can be debugged value' is set to FALSE
- Cleaned up my project
- Deleted the directory containing my app (the build directory I guess)
- Set my scheme to use the Release Build Configuration for Archiving

Is there something I have missed? I'm going nuts after my 20.-something submission :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not using the correct certificates when building your app. Delete your certificates in Provisioning Portal and create new ones and update them in Xcode. Goto Organizer / Provisioning Profiles / Refresh and allow Xcode to fetch the latest ones.

Again, clean all of your targets. You can even go to `/Users/%USERNAME%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete all of the directories in there *(mainly your app in question)*.

Then Under **`TARGET`** in Xcode, goto **Build Settings** and choose the *NEW* certificates.

Also, use **`Archive *(under Product in Xcode 4.0+)*`** in Xcode. When the build is complete, Organizer should open to your `Application Archives`, if not, go there and click on Archives. Select your app and choose `Validate...`, once your app is validated, click `Submit...`.

*Another thing to note is that **`Entitlements.plist`** is no longer needed, so that is not an issue for you.*

Comment: When I delete my Entitlements.plist from my Target's Build settings, I get the following error in the build log:
This bundle is invalid. The application-identifier entitlement is not formatted correctly; it should contain your 10-character App ID Seed, followed by a dot, followed by your bundle identifier: *myidentifier* (-19053)

Comment: Nevermind, added my Entitlements.plist again and the app builds fine.

Comment: Setting the 'application-identifier' to my bundle id did the trick :)

Comment: Could you please tell me what you meant with Entitlements.plist is no longer needed? Because in my case it seemed to be the case that it was needed ...

Comment: The **Entitlements.plist** used to be required for Ad-Hoc builds only and was never necessary for Release builds. That file is basically for debugging your app on the device, or so ad-hoc testers could send you debug information. But building on Release for the App Store should never have anything to do with Entitlements. Just sounds like you had an issue with your bundle id instead.

Comment: I'd just like to add that WrightsCS has solved my head scratching. I simply removed the reference to the Entitlements.plist for the 'release' build and it removed my 'application-identifier' error from iTunes Connect! THANK YOU

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue when i uploaded a file with illegal char in name... i think my illegal char was a space.
also check that your bundle identifier and app ID are correct.

Comment: Where exactly did you have a space? I have a space in my app's name but am unsure which fields to change so that the spaces are still displayed in the App Store or on the Springboard.

Comment: I originally had problems with Xcode uploader, so I saved the archive and used the application loader app, the space was in the file name of the archive that I saved out of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You get 2 trouble incidents with your ADC iOS membership - maybe use one?

Comment: I'd rather not use one of my precious incidents and save them for nasty bugs I can't fix. :) Thanks for the suggestion though! If I can't figure this thing out in a timely manner I think I'll use one of the incidents afterall!

Answer (score 1):

There may be privacy description *(for Services like Camera, Photo Lib, Location)* missing in PList file. Check Thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

For me all i had to do was to pod install because i switched to a different git branch that had different pods configuration