# App Submission: Invalid Binary - Invalid Signature

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, updates, code-signing

I am trying to submit an update to the iOS app store. I am going from a Buzztouch app to a Sprite Kit app. I am able to archive the Xcode project and submit it. The app gets to the status of Upload Received but than about a minute later, it changes to Invalid Binary and I get an email saying:

> Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.

I have cleaned out the build directory, rebuilt my release target, and made new provisioning profiles multiple times. All of the Code Signing Identities are set to iOS Developer. Code signing and the provisioning profiles have always been a little bit confusing to me, I could have made some obvious mistakes.

I have tried submitting over 50 times! I find this very frustrating because I have emailed Apple and they got back to me but it was just a link to the dev center with code signing information. I have also spent lots of time searching the Internet to find a solution to this and there hasn’t been a good solution that actually works for this problem.

The only thing I can think of is either because I am changing from a [Buzztouch](http://buzztouch.com/) app or it is Sprite Kit.

Here is a screenshot of my code signing:

[image: screenshot of code signing]

Comment: Your code signing is wrong.  You need to use **iOS Distribution** for the mode that you want to release with.

Comment: Hello @borrrden I tried changing all of them to iOS Distribution and it still returned with the same thing.

Comment: Change it to iOS distribution and then repeat all of the cleaning steps, etc.  Also you should see a warning in your errors pane if the signing was not performed correctly.  You have an app store certificate right?

Comment: I have an app store certificate but there are no errors anywhere in the process. I am repeating all the steps right now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Well the one thing I can tell you from the information above is that it will never work as long as "iOS Developer" is selected.

Comment: Invalid binary again... anymore ideas??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46291/discussion-between-pokobros-and-borrrden)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the Mac App Store. What's the solution?

Comment: Hello @adib I actually have not had a solution therefore I did not award the bounty to anyone since none of the solutions worked. :) Do you have any suggestions? I think with this type of problem each solution is unique so you can try any of the methods listed on this page, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: @PoKoBros What I did was re-generate the certificates and re-fresh the signing identities before submitting.

Comment: @adib Did that work for you?? Because I have tried that many times and it still has not worked. Can you post a screenshot of how you signed the app? Like mine in the question. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Still no luck. This is very FRUSTRATING!!!!!!!!!!! I have already tried contacting Apple but they did not provide anything that helped. Please can anyone help, I am 13 years old and need some guidance on this!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did when I encountered a similar problem with the Mac App Store:

1. Re-generate the app's Distribution and Development certificates (from the Apple Developer's Certificates site).
2. Download both certificates and drag them to Xcode's icon (not sure whether it had any impact, but after so many submission failures, I was pretty superstitious).
3. Re-fresh the certificates and identities from Xcode.

   1. Open Xcode's Preferences.
   2. Go to Accounts tab.
   3. Clicked my account
   4. Clicked the refresh button.
4. Generate the archive.
5. Submit the app and clicked on "refresh signing identities" somewhere mid-way in wizard prompts.

As a reference, here is my built settings related to signing. That one worked the last time I submitted the app (which has been in the "waiting for review" state for the past two days now, so I guess it passed all of their automated tests).

[image: Build settings - signing]

Comment: Im very displeased that the error email from Apple was misleading. This cost me a LOT of time! Thanks a ton for your working solution!!

Answer (score 3):

In Apple developer support there are two additional common causes of the `Invalid Signature` binary rejection reason,

1. executable files containing special characters (i.e. non-numeric, and non-alpha). To resolve this issue, change the Xcode target’s Product Name build setting from “${TARGET_NAME} to a string containing only alpha/numeric characters. Let me know if this was the cause of the issue (and the problematic characters) because I file bug reports to fix each instance I find here.
2. Apple Double Files ("double files") that result from copying the Xcode project uncompressed to/from a non HFS+ formatted hard drive. To check if this caused your rejection:

A. Run the app diagnostic here: [How do I check if my application's signature has been corrupted?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG38)

B. Then check the command line output with: [List of Signature Verification Failure Root Causes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-TNTAG39). Double files are diagnosed with a message like:

```
resource missing: my.app/._.*
```

C. From the docs:

> The file prefixed with "._" is considered an AppleDouble file and it
>   can result from copying the uncompressed Xcode project folder onto a
>   non-HFS+ formatted disk. The AppleDouble files must be removed using
>   the 'dot_clean' command. The Xcode project folder is the argument to
>   dot_clean as illustrated below. Note: You can drag your Xcode project
>   folder from Finder into the Terminal window to automatically fill its
>   path into the command.

```
        dot_clean /path/to/My_Xcode_Project
```

(If Terminal can't find the dot_clean utility, download the optional Command Line Tools through Xcode > Preferences > Downloads)

D. After running `dot_clean` on your Xcode project, create a new app archive (via Xcode > Product > Archive), reattempt submission.

To prevent double files be sure to compress the Xcode project folder to .zip using Finder before transferring it to/from a non HFS+ formatted hard drive.

Comment: I think No2 caused this problem for me. I tried uploading from external ntfs hard drive. When copied project to the Mac's hard drive, everything passed normally.

Comment: No1 caused my problem. I used "?" character in my product name.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue relate with signing failed because of your app didn't sign with recent distribution certificate. Check the following steps:

1) Check your `bundle identifier` to list out provisioning profile as like below picture. Because It also lead to this problem.

[image]

2)You may not using the `correct certificates` when building your app. Just Delete your certificates in Provisioning Portal and create new ones and update them in Xcode.

3) From your picture, **you didn't selected correct provisioning profile**. Goto Organizer / Provisioning Profiles / Refresh and allow Xcode to fetch the latest ones. see screen shot to how to do that.

Select correct Provisioning profile.
[image]

Select correct code sign.
[image]

4) Cleaned up your project.

5) Just `clean all your targets` . You can even go to `/Users/%USERNAME%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete all of the directories in there.

[see this ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004032/invalid-binary-error-after-app-store-submission)

Comment: Did you delete old certificate before add new  certificate in your keychain?

Answer (score 1):

1. Under "Code Signing Identity" Make sure you have selected your Distribution Cert for the "Release" scheme
2. Under "Provisioning Profile" make sure you select a Distribution provisioning profile (not an Ad Hoc one)
3. Archive and distribute, make sure the same cert is selected when submitting (after entering your iTunesConnect info)

Answer (score 0):

After doing all of the above

Menu Bar
try Product->Archive

Then from the organise try resigning and submitting.

Window->Organiser
 Select archive and then press distribute (but i'm pretty sure you'll know how that works)

Obviously if you can't do this then chances are you have indeed got something wrong with your signing certificates, more specifically your bundle identifier is likely to be the culprit.

One other option is your app uses services that you haven't set up on developer.apple.com/ios for the app id such as game centre, push notification etc.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

check your launch images . Are they conflicting like 2 images have got same name. Because i have got the similar issue which i solved like this within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out this problem I just created a new Xcode project and copied and pasted everything into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was to not ASCII chars in filename (someone did sent us to embed), solution was to do a global search in project:

ls -1 -R -i | grep -a "[^A-Za-z0-9_.':@ /-]"

And delete those chars from filenames.